# C++ Hash Table with Chaining Bug

Tags: c++, hashtable, chaining, chain

For some reason, my code is not running properly. It does compile but when it goes to the output screen, it just says "An error has occurred". It does not list any sorts of errors. I've been trying to find the error in my code for a while but I can't seem to find where it is. Here is my code:

```
class Node
{
private:
    int key;
    int value;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node();
   ~Node();
    void setKey(int num);
    int getKey();
    void setValue(int x);
    int getValue();
    void setNext(Node* theNext);
    Node* getNext();
};

Node::Node()
{
    next = NULL;
}

Node::~Node()
{

}

void Node::setKey(int num)
{
    key = num;
}

int Node::getKey()
{
    return key;
}

void Node::setValue(int x)
{
        value = x;
}

int Node::getValue()
{
    return value;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* theNext)
{
    next = theNext;
}

Node* Node::getNext()
{
    return next;
}

const int SIZE = 7;

class chainTable
{
private:
    Node* data[SIZE];
public:
    chainTable();
    ~chainTable();
    int chainHash(int num);
    void insert(int key, int value);
    void printTable();
};

chainTable::chainTable()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        data[i]->setValue(-1);
    }
}

chainTable::~chainTable()
{

}

int chainTable::chainHash(int num)
{
    return num % 5;
}

void chainTable::insert(int key, int value)
{
    if (data[key]->getValue() == -1)
    {
        data[key] = new Node;
        data[key]->setValue(value);
        data[key]->setKey(key);
        data[key]->setNext(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = data[key];

        while (temp->getNext() != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }

        Node* newEntry = new Node();
        newEntry = temp->getNext();

        newEntry->setKey(key);
        newEntry->setValue(value);
        newEntry->setNext(NULL);        
    }
}

void chainTable::printTable()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        Node* temp = data[i];

        while (temp->getNext())
        {
            cout << temp->getValue();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    chainTable theChain;

    int arr[7] = {1,2,5,7,7,9,1};

    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        int arrHash = theChain.chainHash(arr[i]);
        theChain.insert(arrHash,arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the constructor and in `insert`: There are no `Node` objects, so the `value` can not be set. I also changed `printTable`.
I didn't try it, but like this it should be better:

```
class Node
{
private:
    int key;
    int value;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node();
   ~Node();
    void setKey(int num);
    int getKey();
    void setValue(int x);
    int getValue();
    void setNext(Node* theNext);
    Node* getNext();
};

Node::Node()
{
    next = NULL;
}

Node::~Node()
{

}

void Node::setKey(int num)
{
    key = num;
}

int Node::getKey()
{
    return key;
}

void Node::setValue(int x)
{
        value = x;
}

int Node::getValue()
{
    return value;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* theNext)
{
    next = theNext;
}

Node* Node::getNext()
{
    return next;
}

const int SIZE = 7;

class chainTable
{
private:
    Node* data[SIZE];
public:
    chainTable();
    ~chainTable();
    int chainHash(int num);
    void insert(int key, int value);
    void printTable();
};

chainTable::chainTable()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        //data[i]->setValue(-1);
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}

chainTable::~chainTable()
{
    // ToDo: delete all nodes
}

int chainTable::chainHash(int num)
{
    return num % 5;
}

void chainTable::insert(int key, int value)
{
    if (data[key] == NULL)
    {
        data[key] = new Node;
        data[key]->setValue(value);
        data[key]->setKey(key);
        data[key]->setNext(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = data[key];

        while (temp->getNext() != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }

        Node* newEntry = new Node();
        newEntry = temp->getNext();

        newEntry->setKey(key);
        newEntry->setValue(value);
        newEntry->setNext(NULL);        
    }
}

void chainTable::printTable()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        Node* temp = data[i];

        while (temp)
        {
            cout << temp->getValue();
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    chainTable theChain;

    int arr[7] = {1,2,5,7,7,9,1};

    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        int arrHash = theChain.chainHash(arr[i]);
        theChain.insert(arrHash,arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! Although I changed it, I'm still a bit confused as to why it didn't work in the constructor. Didn't I create the Node array? Node* data[size]. Isn't that a node object?

Comment: `Node* data[]` is an array of pointers to node objects. But in the beginning, there are no objects, that gives the error. In the insert function, with `new Node`, an object is created.